# How to subset by time range?

Tags: r, time, conditional-statements, subset

I would like to create a subset from the following example of data frame. The condition is to select those rows where time column values belong to time range from the minimum time for the certain id till the next lets say one hour.

```
    id    time
    1   1468696537          
    1   1468696637          
    1   1482007490          
    2   1471902849          
    2   1471902850          
    2   1483361074          
    3   1474207754          
    3   1474207744          
    3   1471446673          
    3   1471446693
```

And the output should be like this:

```
   id    time
    1   1468696537          
    1   1468696637          
    2   1471902849          
    2   1471902850          
    3   1471446673          
    3   1471446693
```

Please, help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
library(magrittr);
library(dplyr);
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(time <= min(time) + 3600)
#     id       time
#  <int>      <int>
#1     1 1468696537
#2     1 1468696637
#3     2 1471902849
#4     2 1471902850
#5     3 1471446673
#6     3 1471446693
```

Explanation: Group entries by `id`, then `filter` entries that are within `min(time) + 1 hour`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   id    time
    1   1468696537
    1   1468696637
    1   1482007490
    2   1471902849
    2   1471902850
    2   1483361074
    3   1474207754
    3   1474207744
    3   1471446673
    3   1471446693  ", header = T)
```